# adding style to a html table dynamically - using DOM, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

could you take a look at the following fiddle:..I am using JS for my project

```
http://jsfiddle.net/dgqr2nLd/7/
```

I have the layout of the table the way I want with padding, border colour etc...

In my project however I can't seem to get this result. I am using DOM elements to dynamically create a html table in my application and the inner.html is as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Images</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <center>
        <b><font color="FF6600"> Feature Properties </font></b>
    </center>
    <br>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><b>id</b></td>
                <td>11079<br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>one</b></td>
                <td>d<br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>two</b></td>
                <td>d<br></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><b>three</b></td>
                <td>d<br></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    <a id="lb1" href="http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg" rel="lightbox[me]">
        <img src="http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg" width="200" height="200">
    </a>
</div>
```

So iv tired to update the table appearance of the table by:

```
var Newtable = document.createElement('table');
Newtable.rules = "all";
Newtable.cellpadding = "10px 10px 10px 10px";
NewTable.style = "border: 1px solid #CCCCCC";
```

### this didnt work

---

tried

```
    NewTable.class = "WorkFlowLayout"

 .WorkFlowLayout
    {
        rules=all;
         cellpadding=10px 10px 10px 10px;
          border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    }
```

this didnt work

### -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

I can get the border to appear by using

```
Newtable.border = "1";
```

but cant get the rules, or cellPadding to work...any idea as to why?

### ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**UPDATE**

iv used

```
'var Newtable = document.createElement('table');
 Newtable.setAttribute('border', '1');
 Newtable.setAttribute("cellPadding", "20px 20px 20px 20px");`
```

and this returns `<table border="1" cellpadding="20px 20px 20px 20px">
<tbody><tr><td><b>id</b></td><td>13083<br></td></tr><tr><td><b>one</b></td><td>ujuj<br></td></tr><tr><td><b>two</b></td><td>uju<br></td></tr><tr><td><b>three</b></td><td>ujuj<br></td></tr></tbody></table>` which has the cellpadding in the correct place but it doesnt change anything in the table layout? any ideas?>

Also when I use :

```
     var Newtable = document.createElement('table');
        NewTable.setAttribute("className","WorkFlowLayout");

    .WorkFlowLayout
{
   /* rules:all;
     cellpadding:10px 10px 10px 10px; */
      border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

This flags an error with NewTable.setAttribute("className","WorkFlowLayout"); saying newTable doesnt exist, because as im creating it dynamically and passing it back it doesnt exist. how do i add the style from here thanks?

Comment: css rules don't have an equal between the property and the value, but a double colon : .

Comment: There seems to be confusion here between HTML attributes and CSS. With CSS, the table does not need to exist beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

When manipulating styles of some DOM element via JS, it is probably the most easy way to set a new class name to that element. So I would go with your second approach.

There ist only a minor mistake in it – it is `Element.className` instead of `Element.class`.

Your second example should work as expected, when using the following:

```
// This will overwrite any existing class names
NewTable.className = "WorkFlowLayout";

// This would add another class to an existing list of class names
NewTable.classList.add( "WorkFlowLayout" );
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but when I try NewTable.className = "WorkFlowLayout"; it flags an error saying NewTable does not exist..as I am creating the html table dynamically... Do I have to wait to innerHTML is passed back then somehow apply style?

Comment: @John No, you can prepare an element and then inject it into the DOM. I *guess* that the problem is somewhere else…